# Set sass options in Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to change the behavior of sass in Rails application but with no effect. Here is a summary what I did so far.

I've added

```
  config.sass.style = :compressed
```

in config/application.rb then restarted the server but no effect. After that I decided to try with config/environments/development.rb but same.

So my question is how to change sass options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a file in `config/initializers` ie `config/initializers/sass_options.rb` then add the following in the file:

```
require 'sass/plugin'    
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
```

Restart the server and do a new try

**Edit:**

Are you using `sass-rails` gem? If you are running in development mode it looks like is hard-coded to 'expanded' https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Tried but got an error. /Users/trooper/Projects/rails/blog/config/initializers/sass_options.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)

Comment: You have 'sass' gem in Gemfile right?, BTW I've edited the answer including 'require'

Comment: Yes I have sass in gemfile. After adding the require method I have no errors but the output of the css is not compressed as specified in the option line.

Comment: If you are running in development mode it looks like sass is always 'expanded'